# BASH: How can i use "read" with parameters two times?

Tags: database, bash

I wanted to write the read in foo.sh with this script:

```
b=1
c=1
y=1
echo "What is the name for the $((b++)) database ?"
read name$((c++))

echo $name$((y++)) >> foo.sh
```

I want that in foo.sh stands:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

BUT there only stands

```
1
2
3
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `read <var>` on a separate line. Also one of your variable is not needed. Try this -

```
b=1
c=1
echo "What is the name for the $((b++)) database ?"
read name
name=$name$((c++))
echo $name >> foo.sh
```

Comment: Yes, thank you !
echo $name >> foo.sh
else in foo ist standing name11 name22 etc.

Comment: Okay. I get it. I'll edit my answer. Also do you want to run a loop over this?